# Counting the number of unconnected subgraphs

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, graphs-and-networks

If I have a `Graph`, how can I count how many disconnected pieces it has? Mathematica must know this since it is able to separate them out when it displays the graph, but I can't find any function which gives the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual term is *connected components*.

You can use `Length@WeaklyConnectedComponents[graph]`.  This will work on directed graphs as well, assuming that you are looking for the components of the underlying undirected graph.

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) also has a fast function for measuring the sizes of connected components without actually returning them: `IGWeaklyConnectedComponentSizes`.

Answer (score 6):

Shortly after posting this I found that I can use

`Length@ConnectedGraphComponents`

to get the desired number.